How do I find the maximum sum given the data of a sample?
There are $132$ shops in the giant mall. A group of this mall's investors did an independent research and found out the following income of $10$ of these shops: $124, 74, 101, 145, 87, 42, 124, 59, 119, 95$.
Considering the distribution being normal, determine with $99\%$ reliability the maximum income of all shops in that mall.

Here is what I did:
I can find out the maximum income, the sample mean, a

We find the maximum income of the sample. The maximum income is $145$.

We find the mean income of the sample. For this, we use the arithmetic mean formula:


$$
\bar{x} = \dfrac{124 + 74 + 101 + 145 + 87 + 42 + 124 + 59 + 119 + 95}{10} = 97
$$

We find the sample standard deviation based on the sample of $n$ shops. For this, we use the formula:

$$
s = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}}
$$
Let's find the terms $(x_i)$ one by one from the sample:
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= (124-97)^2 = 729 \\
x_2 &= (74-97)^2 = 529 \\
x_3 &= (101-97)^2 = 16 \\
x_4 &= (145-97)^2 = 2304 \\
x_5 &= (87-97)^2 = 100 \\
x_6 &= (42-97)^2 = 3025 \\
x_7 &= (124-97)^2 = 729 \\
x_8 &= (59-97)^2 = 1444 \\
x_9 &= (119-97)^2 = 484 \\
x_{10} &= (95-97)^2 = 4 \\
\end{align*}
$$
Summing them all up, we get:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{10}(x_i - \bar{x})^2 = 729+529+16+2304+100+3025+729+1444+484+4 = 9364
$$
Then, calculating $s$, we get:
$$
s = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{9364}{10-1}} \approx 32.2
$$
How do I proceed further?

I don't see how the given data could possibly lead to such a certain result.  I expect you are to make some (very strong) assumptions.  Like that the distribution is normal or whatever.  Absent assumptions like that, not a lot can be said.

Expecting a $99%$ reliability with a sample of less than $10%$ of the data doesn't sound right.

Oh. I clarified that this problem has a normal distribution. As for the $10%$, uh, oh well, it's how it's given.

(Not so sure but) Since your sample is small, Maybe this $z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$? and for 1% rejection, i guess you can find it in the normal table accordingly

There are three issues:

the sensitivity of any analysis on "considering the distribution being normal"
the distribution of the sample statistics
the distribution of the maximum of a distribution where some of the data is known but most is not.

You could try a simulation to estimate the confidence interval. Here is one using R which tries to deal with the second and third points, though there may be better ways of doing this:
simulatemax <- function(popsize, obs){
  numobs <- length(obs)
  meanobs <- mean(obs)
  varobs <- var(obs)
  simmean <- rnorm(1, meanobs, sqrt(varobs/numobs))
  simvar <- (numobs-1) * varobs / rchisq(1, numobs-1)
  simobs <- rnorm(popsize-numobs, simmean, sqrt(simvar))
  simmax <- max(c(obs, simobs))
  return(simmax)
  }

set.seed(2024)
sims <- replicate(10^5, simulatemax(popsize=132, 
                   obs=c(124, 74, 101, 145, 87, 42, 124, 59, 119, 95)))
conf <- 0.99
quantile(sims, c((1-conf)/2, (1+conf)/2))
#      0.5%   99.5% 
#   145.000 303.919

So this particular simulation suggests a $99\%$ confidence interval of about $[145,304]$.
The possibility that the maximum of the $132$ values could be equal to the maximum of the $10$ observations is plausible; if you did not look at the observations, you might think the probability of this event could be $\frac{10}{132} \approx 0.076$, so well within the confidence interval.
Using a different seed might change the upper end slightly.
The interval could be substantially different is you assumed some other underlying distribution.
